# SWIFT_VERSION Error on every time pod update

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Every time I update Podfile, have to fix this SWIFT_VERSION error to resolve.

How to set pod and swift version to unique, so that each time when update pod need not to fix SWIFT_VERSION error.

```
Error: SWIFT_VERSION '5.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2.  (in target 'paper-onboarding')
```

Due to operating system constraints, X-Code allow to run swift maximum of 4.2.

Swift 5.0 will not support, Have to bring it down to 4.2 version for compatible and run the application on simulator or device.

Answer (score 0):

Add this below your pods definitions in your `Podfile`.
Insert the pod you want inside `{pod-name}` and set the version you need

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == '{pod-name}'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
      end
    end
  end
end
```